# Proper way to initialize variables inside scope in Rust

Tags: rust, scope, initialization

I'm new to Rust, and wanna write some simple game.

In the code below I have some peace of code, where I define riddler and guesser between 2 players of the game.

```rs
enum PlayerMovingPosition{
    Riddler,
    Guesser,
}

struct Player {
    name: String,
    moving_position: Option<PlayerMovingPosition>,
}

struct Game {
    player1: Player,
    player2: Player,
}

fn define_riddler_n_guesser(&self) {
    let mut riddler: &Player;
    let mut guesser: &Player;
    for player in [&self.player1, &self.player2] {
        match player.moving_position {
            Some(PlayerMovingPosition::Riddler) => riddler = player,
            Some(PlayerMovingPosition::Guesser) => guesser = player,
            _ => panic!("Hey damba, player {} moving position is undefined!", player.name.as_str()),
        }
    
    //... Place where I got the error
    }
```

I've got the [E0381 error](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0381), that says that the variables may be unitialized there.

I went through some searching and got condractiory answers, like:

- some people claimed that it's bad practice to declare variables without initializing it, and it leads to bugs; they adviced to use some iterationg magic I can't get now cause of my poor rust skill.
- others said that it's a proper way, and is used in situations like:

```rs
let lol;
{
    lol = "kek";
}
println!(lol);
// kek
```

I found it contoversial and I can't decide what to do in my case, but I bet they aren't contradictiory, they are about different things, and I can't see this difference due to poor understanding.

It would be fine if you tell me if I wrote bad code in rust and show me the right one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by using a the match pattern.
This match pattern will assure both `riddler` and `guesser` are always assigned

```rust
        let (riddler, guesser) = match (&self.player1.moving_position, &self.player2.moving_position) {
            (Some(PlayerMovingPosition::Riddler), Some(PlayerMovingPosition::Guesser)) => (&mut self.player1, &mut self.player2),
            (Some(PlayerMovingPosition::Guesser), Some(PlayerMovingPosition::Riddler)) => (&mut self.player2, &mut self.player1),
            _ => panic!("Unsupported combo"),
        };
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=233c40d2cde518af67b0af08c2c33893)

Comment: I'm not sure that it's the best solution from the point of rust style code, cause it looks too complex, but I'm so far from the rust code style conventions and regard this as much suitable for my case

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the cleanest way to write it in rust. But personally I would return an `Err` instead of using `panic!` to make it more idiomatic rust

Comment: @Dominux: The complexity is from the under-constrained types you're using. Example, why is `moving_position` an Option if you require it anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of my observations:

- It looks `define_riddler_n_guesser` is a method of the `Game` struct. If so, it needs to be put in `impl Game { ... }`. In that context, `self` represents the struct instance on which the method is called upon.
- If the field `moving_position` of a player cannot be `None`, there is no need of using `Option`.
- Both of the opinions on variable initiation are correct to me. A variable cannot be used without being initialized.

Here is the code revised based on the above points. Just for your reference.

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]
enum PlayerMovingPosition{
    Riddler,
    Guesser,
}

struct Player {
    name: String,
    moving_position: PlayerMovingPosition,
}

struct Game {
    player1: Player,
    player2: Player,
}

impl Game {
    fn define_riddler_n_guesser(&mut self) {
        let (riddler, guesser) = 
            if self.player1.moving_position == PlayerMovingPosition::Riddler { 
                (&mut self.player1, &mut self.player2)
            } else {
                (&mut self.player2, &mut self.player1)
            };
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7f0671ee96ea63e47b72dcddab98aadf)

Comment: I implemented this function as method in my local code, but simplified during rewriting the code here, cause I see hard readable long code in other questions and try to avoid it in mine;
But it's just clarifiing, and it's not against your solution)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you could take a slightly different approach: Save the roles of the players in the game instance. That would make swapping the roles easier and fix your error (because the riddler and guesser is always be defined).

The code would be the following:

```
struct Player {
    name: String,
}

struct Game {
    player1: Player,
    player2: Player,
    player1_is_riddler: bool,
}

impl Game {
    fn define_riddler_n_guesser(&self) {
        let (riddler, guesser) = if self.player1_is_riddler {
            (&self.player1, &self.player2)
        } else {
            (&self.player2, &self.player1)
        };
        //... Place where you got the error
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought a lot of where to store data about player's position, cause each player makes a move, implemented in itself, so it should be aware of his position/role